# Why is there a gap between image and navigation bar

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm having some trouble removing a small gap between an image and my navigation bar. I've honestly tried just about everything i can think of. Setting inline-blocks on my ul and li level, and using text-align: left don't seem to be moving the hyperlinks to the left-most side of the div, and from there I'm not to sure what should be done. There is a padding, but it shouldn't be causing that much of a gap.

Here is the html code:

```
        <div id = "header">
        <img src ="img.png"/>   
           <div id ="nav_bar">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class= "nav"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class= "nav"><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
                <li class= "nav"><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
                <li class= "nav"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li class= "nav"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
```

Here's a jfiddle describing what I'm talking about.
http://jsfiddle.net/37VZb/1/

To clarify the gap I'm talking about is between the right of the image and the left most nav bar element.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because of a space character between inline(-block) elements. This could be fixed by commenting that space out this way:

```
<img src ="http://www.leapcms.com/images/100pixels1.gif"/><!--
--><div id ="nav_bar"> ...
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/37VZb/4/)**.

Similar topic on SO:

- [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

And a good reference:

- http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

#### Update

The remaining space belongs to the user agent applied style on the `<ul>` element.

Web browsers usually apply some padding on the list elements. To remove that set `padding: 0;` as follows:

```css
ul.nav { padding : 0; }
```

Here is the **[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/37VZb/7/)**.

Comment: *Well*, Using `inline-block`s has its own pros and cons.

Comment: That seems to help a bit, but there is still a 60px~ gap between the picture and the nav bar. The padding is another 20px, so where would the rest be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Your gap is a white space like you find in between words since both element are set as inline boxes. **In your CSS you set as well somme padding to ul and a , they both are there.**
http://jsfiddle.net/37VZb/8/

```
.nav_bar, .nav{
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

To get rid of it:

1) do not indent your code and get closing and opening brackets of element touch each other

2) add a CSScomment in between to swallow that white-space

3) set font-size to 0 (0.01px for IE) to parent of these inline-boxes and reset it ot back to 1rem (and or px/pt) for img (alt) and nav_bar

negative margin or negative letter-spacing are not to be used, it is not reliable and not meant to care about this

Answer (score 0):

is this what you mean? You can target the `nav` class on your `ul` and adjust the default margins that are being assigned

```
ul.nav{
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/37VZb/5/)