# Space between nowrap inline blocks

Tags: html, css

I want to have several block elements next to each other, which take the full browser width.

With `white-space: nowrap`, it works quite well, but there is a random space of a few pixels in between one element and another:

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#container1 { white-space: nowrap; position: absolute; width: 100%; }
#container1 div { display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 200px; }
```

```html
<div id="container1">
    <div style="background: red;"></div>
    <div style="background: yellow;"></div>
    <div style="background: green;"></div>
    <div style="background: blue;"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the [jsBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/peqevamu/2/edit).

It is no padding, no margin, no border, no offset.

Comment: I can't see any white space. Not even a pixel.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ Check this out: http://jsbin.com/peqevamu/4/edit

Comment: You have to scroll to the right.. there is a space of about 8px next to the coloured blocks.. (tested in IE, Chrome, Firefox) Windows 7.

Comment: @ChristophBühler oh sorry! i see the white space now.

Comment: @HashemQolami answered the question :) thanks.

Comment: @ChristophBühler I'm about to post the answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because of a space character between inline(-block) elements (a line break and a few tabs counts as a space), This could be fixed by commenting that space out this way:

```
<div style="background: red;"></div><!-- 
 --><div style="background: yellow;"></div><!-- 
 --><div style="background: green;"></div><!-- 
 --><div style="background: blue;"></div>
```

**[Online Demo](http://jsbin.com/peqevamu/4/edit)**.

Actually, it's not a bug, it's the normal behavior of the inline elements; Just like when you place an image next to a line of text, or put a button next to an input element.

There are couple of ways to remove the space between inline(-block) elements:

- Minimized the HTML
- Negative margins
- Comment the white space out
- Break the closing tag
- Set the font size of the parent to zero then reset that for children
- Float the inline items instead
- Use flexbox

Check the [Chris Coyier's Article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/), or these similar topics on SO:

- [Why is there a gap between image and navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290481/why-is-there-a-gap-between-image-and-navigation-bar/21290571#21290571)
- [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)
- [A Space between Inline-Block List Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256533/a-space-between-inline-block-list-items)
- [How to remove "Invisible space" from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12183341/how-to-remove-invisible-space-from-html)

Answer (score 4):

I've faced this problem once and I used this CSS property. sometimes its help.

`font-size:0;`

Answer (score 0):

Just try and have all the div's into single each. Sometimes white-space doesn't work as what we want.

http://jsbin.com/peqevamu/8/