# Div inside overflow="auto" to auto size its width to its contents

Tags: html, css

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<div class="scrollingBox">
    <div class="container">
         <div class="item">Item</div>
         <div class="item">Item</div>
         <div class="item">Item</div>
         <div class="item">Item</div>
    </div>
</div
```

**Here is my CSS:**

```
.scrollingBox {
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    overflow:auto;
}
.item {
    float:left;
    height:60px;
    margin:5px;
    width:100px;
}
```

The `.container` can contain any number of `.item`s.

My problem at the moment is the `.container` will never go wider than the `.scrollingBox`, and the scrolling box ends up with a vertical scroll bar, and the `.item`s end up stacking vertically. I give the `.container` a fixed height, but the `.item`s stack vertically beyond this fixed height.

I want the `.container` to have no fixed width, so it can take any number of items. I want the scroll bar to be horizontal, and I also want the `.item`s to stack horizontally.

**My question:**

What CSS do I apply to `.container` to make the `.item`s stack horizontally?

Comment: the `.tems` should be floated next to each other until the end of `.scrollingBox` is reached, so basically there should be 3 items next to each other before they break. Do you want every item to be in one line and have the scrollingBox have a horizontal scrollbar as soon as there are more then 3 items?

Comment: @NicoO pretty much yeah

Comment: Then you have your answers below. Good luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using `float` property, the elements are removed from document normal flow.

You can change their display type to `inline-block` too keep them in inline flow, and use [`white-space: nowrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) for the container (`.scrollingBox`) to keep the inline items beside each others, as follows

Here you go:

```css
.scrollingBox {
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    overflow:auto;
    white-space: nowrap;    /* Suppress line breaks */
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;  /* Display the items as inline-block            */
    vertical-align: top;    /* Align the inline items vertically at the top */
    height:60px;
    width:100px;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/nK37Z/)**.

**Note:** You can refer [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875226/space-between-nowrap-inline-blocks/21875532#21875532) to remove the white space between inline-block elements.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:inline-block` to your `.item`
The default `display` for `DIV`s is `block` and this cause a vertical stack, But `display:inline-block` makes all `DIV`s to arrange them self in a horizontal line

Difference of varient display options:

**Inline elements:**

- Respect left & right margins and padding, but **not** top & bottom
- **Cannot** have a width and height set
- Allow other elements to sit to their left and right.

**Block elements:**

- Respect all of those
- Force a line break after the block element

**Inline-block elements:**

- Allow other elements to sit to their left and right
- Respect top & bottom margins and padding
- Respect height and width.

Derived from [Oldskool answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189873/1841194)
More info in [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)