# How to make responsive two inline-block divs

Tags: html, css

My HTML:

```
<div class="sameline">       
   <div class="same_vertical">       
    <div class="textline">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis consequat tellus a fermentum. Maecenas convallis, nunc eget  
      porttitor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis consequat tellus a fermentum. Maecenas convallis, nunc 
      eget  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis consequat tellus a fermentum. Maecenas convallis, nunc eget            porttitor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis consequat tellus a fermentum. Maecenas convallis, nunc           eget  psum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis consequat tellus a fermentum. Maecenas convallis, nunc eget  
      porttitor Lorem  porttitor
      porttitor
    </div> 
   </div><!--same_vertical-->        


   <div class="same_vertical">       
    <div class="textline">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis consequat tellus a fermentum. Maecenas convallis, nunc eget  
      porttitor Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis consequat tellus a fermentum. Maecenas convallis, nunc 
      eget  psum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis consequat tellus a fermentum. Maecenas convallis, nunc eget  
      porttitor Lorem  porttitor
    </div> 
   </div><!--same_vertical--> 
 </div> <!--sameline-->
```

My CSS:

```
.sameline {
    text-align:left;
    max-width: 1105px;
    margin:0 auto;  
}
.same_vertical {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top:-7px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    max-width: 530px;
}

.textline {
    border-top-width: thin;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #CCC; 
    padding-top:10px;   
    color: #626262;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P6Umg/

My problem is I cannot make `.sameline` responsive; I mean everytime I shrink my browser window the second piece of text falls above the first one instead of shrinking both of them. I thought it 'd behave like a single div with max-width. In which way may I oblige the whole .sameline shrinks as a whole?

Comment: It is behaving like a single `<div>`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep these two `inline-block` elements beside each other, you should use percentage values for the `width` and `left-margin` properties, as follows:

```css
.sameline {
    max-width: 1105px;
    margin:0 auto; 
    text-align: center;
}

.same_vertical {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top:-7px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 45%;
}

 /* remove left margin for the first column */
.sameline :first-child {margin-left: 0;}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/bmFpK/)**.

**Note:** There's a **white space** between inline(-block) elements. You should remove that to prevent unexpected issues. You can refer **[my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875226/space-between-nowrap-inline-blocks/21875532#21875532)**.