# Center image Y and X within DIV

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/cECRj/

How would I center the image so that it is in the complete center of the DIV?

```
#box
{
border: 1px solid;
margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
width: 250px;
height: 200px;
border-radius: 35px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 35px; 
-moz-border-radius: 35px; 
border: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
display:inline-block;
}

<div id="box">
<img src="cleaning1.jpg" height="150px" width="200px">
</div>
```

Comment: In order to align an image with unknown dimensions vertically and horizontally center, you can refer [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474).

Comment: will the image size change?

Comment: @HashemQolami I tired but I couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the default display type of the image to `inline-block` and create a full-height pseudo-element beside that which is `inline-block` too.

Then align the inline elements vertically by `vertical-align: middle;` and get the image to the center by using `text-align: center;` for the parent `#box`.

Also, there will be a white space character between inline(-block) elements you have to remove it. you can refer [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875226/space-between-nowrap-inline-blocks/21875532#21875532) to do that.

Here you go:

```css
#box {
    /* Other styles here... */

    text-align: center;  /* align the inline(-block) elements horizontally */
    font: 0/0 a;         /* remove the gap between inline(-block) elements */
}

#box:after {         /* create a full-height inline block pseudo=element */
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */
    height: 100%;
}

#box img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;  /* vertical alignment of the inline element */  
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/J7xha/)**

For further details you can refer to **[my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474)**.

Comment: Thank you. I did not do it this way that is why it did not work.

Comment: Hashem, would there be a reason as to why my txt is not appearing in the box div? My plan was to center the image and then write above it. But no text shows up if I put it in.

Comment: If that is what you want, then use my solution as the text will float on top. That is a much better way to solve your problem than adding unneccassary elements and css code, which really doesn't need to be there.

Comment: @user3354493 `My plan was to center the image and then write above it` well you should note that in your question. In this case, it's better to use the image as **background-image** as *PellePenna* suggested. And if you want to align the **text** center both vertically/horizontally, you can follow *[my approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474)* described at the first section. **[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/VsakD/11/)**

Comment: I was using a pattern as the background for the DIV but i guess I can go without it.

Comment: @user3354493 You can use multiple background images. here is the **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/DQGZt/)**

Answer (score 0):

use [`flexbox`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically)!

```
<div id="box" style = 'display:flex'>
    <div style = 'margin:auto'>
       <img src="cleaning1.jpg" height="150px" width="200px">
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: I wrapped the image inside of a div rather than simply giving the image the style attribute `margin:auto` because I have noticed in some cases that the image width/height parameters are not respected otherwise.