# How I can center a menu bar with ul

Tags: html, css

I have a simple menu bar inside a div and I can center the div but I want to center the menu bar inside the div.

This is the code:

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}


.menu {
    height: 35px;
    width: auto;
    background: url("../img/slash-layer.png") repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(130, 28, 107);
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

ul#navmenu, ul.sub1, ul.sub2 {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 9pt;
    max-width: 660px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul#navmenu li {
    width: 125px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
ul#navmenu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
ul#navmenu .sub1 li {
}
ul#navmenu .sub1 a {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
ul#navmenu .sub2 a {
    margin-left: 3px;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover > a {
    background-color: #CFC;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover a:hover {
    background-color: #FF0;
}
ul#navmenu ul.sub1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    left: 0px;
}
ul#navmenu ul.sub2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 126px;
}
ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1 {
    display: block;
}
ul#navmenu .sub1 li:hover .sub2 {
    display: block;
}
.darrow {
    font-size: 11pt;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 4px;
}
.rarrow {
    font-size: 13pt;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    right: 4px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="recursos/css/main.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="menu">
    <ul id="navmenu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Novedades</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Categorías <span class="darrow">▼</span></a>
        <ul class="sub1">
            <li><a href="#">Acción</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Aventuras</a></li>
        </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile <span class="darrow">▼</span></a>
        <ul class="sub1">
            <li><a href="#">Menu 4.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 4.2 <span class="rarrow">▶</span></a>
            <ul class="sub2">
                <li><a href="#">Menu 4.2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 4.2.2</a></li>
            </ul></li>
        </ul></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</head>
<body>
```

I tried to put

```
ul#navmenu {
    display: block
}
```

but it doesn't work and I don't understand what... Because I can center the div...

How I can do it?

Comment: maybe because it's `ul#navmenu` instead of `ul#navbar` ?

Comment: Your CSS rule should be `display: block;`, not `display.block`.

Comment: The `ul` element is aligned at the center. The point is that the list items are floated to the left. You can use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` for the list items, and use `text-align: center` for the `ul`

Comment: Sidenote - Your <head> tag should close before your <body> content begins. Also, your <body> only has a closing tag so it technically never begins.

Comment: You shouldn't be putting all of that in your `<head>` tags. Everything after your `<meta>`tags should be inside your `<body>`.

Comment: Hashem it doesnt work Lokesh i have wrote bad my answer

Comment: TylerH yes sorry I put it on the body but i have the problem yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, please note that you should put the elements inside the `<body>` tag.

Actually, The `ul` element is aligned at the center (See **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/pN78K/)**). But the point is that the list items are **floated** to the left.

There are **tow** options:

1. Using a proper fixed width (or max-width as you did) for the `<ul>` element. **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/pN78K/1/)**
2. Or use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` for the list items, and use `text-align: center` for the `ul` to align the inline elements horizontally. **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/pN78K/2/)**.

But **note** that there is a *white space* between inline(-block) elements, which absolutely the normal behavior of inline elements in inline flow. You can refer **[my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875226/space-between-nowrap-inline-blocks/21875532#21875532)** to fix that.

Comment: @Ninjacu You are welcome. please also consider my update to prevent unexpected issues.

Answer (score 1):

First off all, make sure the div is wider that the menu bar.
You can try

```
display:inline
```

or if not

```
text-align:center;
```

for the div

Comment: Ok thanks it works with text-align: center; in the div thanks really!

Comment: No prob, im in the same zone with you when it comes to these kind of problems :D

Answer (score 0):

Could very well be that the width you're trying to set is too big? 
http://jsfiddle.net/As98Q/

```
width: 550px;
```