# Can't get NavBar TRULY centered in wrap

Tags: css, center, navbar, indentation

I've been working on my navbar and with the help of this site, managed to find out how to center it using text align. However, there is a weird indent that I cannot account for in my navbar as you can see in the example so when I center it, it's taking the indent into consideration too, so it doesn't look right.

How do I remove this indent and have it centered properly? I'm rather new to this, so advice would be great. Many thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/f2eNm/

HTML

```
<div class="links_container">
  <div class="nav1">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="noBorder leftedge">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Challenges</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Progress</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="rightedge">Forum</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
margin:0;
}
.links_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #33C4AB;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border-bottom-style: double;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    border-color: #000000;
    /* [disabled]-webkit-box-sizing: inherit; */
    /* [disabled]-moz-box-sizing: inherit; */
    /* [disabled]box-sizing: inherit; */
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
.nav1 {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
.nav1 ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
.nav1 ul li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #333333;
    display: inherit;
    height: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-left: thin solid #CCCCCC;
}
.noBorder {
    border-left-style: none !important;
}
.nav1 ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
}
.leftedge {
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
.rightedge {
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can center a menu bar with ul](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236080/how-i-can-center-a-menu-bar-with-ul)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change some things.

```
.nav1
{
    text-align: center;
}

.nav1 ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f2eNm/3/

Comment: That's great, thank you very much! It was annoying me quite a bit, I spent hours over the last day trying to get it.