# Navigation Bar into Center

Tags: html, css

Hey guys this thing is driving me crazy, i can seem to get my navigation bar to float into the center. tried everything and cant seem to find a simple explanation. any help greatly appreciated

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="sixteen columns header">
<h1>Learn Guitar Online</h1>
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="signup.php">Sign UP</a></li>
<li><a href="forum.php">Forum</a></li>
<li><a href="video.php">Video</a></li>
<li><a href="other.php">Other</a></li>
</ul>   
</div>
```

more html...

css

```
.container .sixteen.columns.headerul.nav li { 

}
.container .sixteen.columns.header ul.nav li a{
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: `margin: 0 auto;`? You claim that you've "tried everything" yet the CSS you've provided has no alignment styling whatsoever...

Comment: `tried everything`... Yet the most basic and well known way to center an element solves your problem..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can center a menu bar with ul](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236080/how-i-can-center-a-menu-bar-with-ul)

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` won't work unless you have specified a width, and that is not always desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/8WYna/)

CSS

```
container{
    text-align:center; /* center child content */
    width:100%; /* be the max available (page) width */
}
ul{
    margin:0 auto; /* dont offset the top/bottom of the elemtent but automatically calculate left/right  offset (margin) */
    width:300px; /* set a fixed width for the element so it has a relative size to align vs its parent*/
}
li{
    display:inline-block; /* display list items on a single line */
}
```

You need to tell the list (`ul`) how to align itself, this can be done by giving it a fixed with and a `margin` of `0 auto` within a container of width `100%` with centrally aligned text.

To get the `li` on the same line you need to make them `display:inline-block`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, and such  a useful tool JSFiddle is!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add a fixed width to your menu you can use `text-align: center` on you `<ul>` and `display: inline-block` for the `<li>` elements.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/8WYna/3/)**

Full CSS

```
html, body{
    width:100%;
}
container{
    width:100%;
}
ul{
    padding: 0;
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
}
li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a width to the nav and margin: 0 auto

For more centering tips, read this:

http://www.tipue.com/blog/center-a-div/

If you want the nav to always be visible, you will need position: fixed as well.