# Centering a navigation menu

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, center

I've been having trouble centereing a navigation bar on blogger. I seems like a very easy thing to do normally but this time its troublesome.

Take a look at the website: [Center Navigation](http://www.hannahallinson.com)

I've tried text-align, margin:0 auto; etc etc. Nothings seems to work!

If someone could help me out that would be great, cheers

Current code:

```
.nav{
position: relative;
margin: auto;
list-style-type: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
list-style:none;
text-align:center;

}

li {
    display:inline-block;
}


<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="http://www.hannahallinson.com/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.hannahallinson.com/p/about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.hannahallinson.com/p/contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://www.instagram.com/hannahallinson">Instagram</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/hannahallinson">Twitter</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can center a menu bar with ul](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236080/how-i-can-center-a-menu-bar-with-ul)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float: left;` to `.tabs .widget li, .tabs .widget li`

**Try This:**

```
.tabs .widget li, .tabs .widget li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

**Instead of:**

```
.tabs .widget li, .tabs .widget li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Both `text-align:center` and `margin:0 auto` can logically only work if the element to be centered has a non-default width, since that is otherwise `auto`, which for a `block` element is 100%. An element that fills up its entire parent cannot be centered.

Give `ul.nav` a fixed width and it will center.

To use `text-align:center` you will need to restrict the `ul` as well, for example by also making it `display:inline-block`. [See this sample](http://jsbin.com/jowagayeyato/1/edit).

Answer (score 0):

add     text-align:center; to the parent div