# Two column fluid layout which the left column is temporary

Tags: html, css

This is a bit of a conundrum. I have a templating system where I want to have a two column layout with a *fixed* width **left** column and a *fluid* **right** column.

However, within the template, sometimes the *left* column won't show and I don't want the layout to break and still have the *right* column to extend all the way across.

Example 1:

```
<div id="left_column">
    300px fixed width
</div>
<div id="right_column">
    Remaining width
</div>
```

Example 2:

```
<div id="right_column">
    Remaining 100% width
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) property to float the left column.

Then can use [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+` to select the `#right_column` that immediately follows the `#left_column` in order to apply a left margin on that element.

<sub>**Note:** adding `margin-left` property prevents the right column from going beneath the left one. *You can verify this by using background colors for the columns and setting different heights.*</sub>

Here you go:

```css
#left_column {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
}

#left_column + #right_column {
  margin-left: 300px;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/bidej/1/edit)**.

In this case, without the `#left_column`, the right column won't have any margin of its left side.

Comment: i prefer `display:inline-block` than float.

Comment: @TilwinJoy That's okay, but note that there will be a [white space between inline-block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875226/space-between-nowrap-inline-blocks/21875532#21875532) elements as they're in inline flow, which you have to remove that.

Comment: thanks for the info. i'm trying to avoid floating ever since i've seen the `clearfix` classes :)