# How do you centre a group of divs inside a containing div?

Tags: css, html, center

I have a group of columns that need to be centred inside a container div with a background colour of #eeeff3  so that when you zoom out the columns stay the same size and centred and the grey background stays 100% width.click the link to see the current html and css!
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2GM6K/)

Can anyone shed some light on the situation?

```
jsfiddle links require code
```

Comment: Please post your HTML & Current CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `float:left` and add `display:inline-block`.

See updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2GM6K/1/)

```
.container{
     margin:0 auto;
     background: #eeeff3;
     width:100%;
     height:400px;
     text-align:center;
}
.col4{
    width:270px;
    height:400px;
    border-right:2px solid white;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: +1 Also mind the [gap between inline(-block) elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875226/space-between-nowrap-inline-blocks/21875532#21875532).

Answer (score 1):

```
.container{
     margin:0 auto;
     background: #eeeff3;
     width:100%;
     height:400px;
     text-align:center;
}
.col4{
    width:270px;
    height:400px;
    border-right:2px solid white;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this css work well:**

```
.container{
     margin:0 auto;
     background: #eeeff3;
     width:100%;
     height:400px;
     text-align:center;

}
.col4{
    float:left;
    width:270px;
    height:400px;
    border-right:2px solid white;
    display:inline-block;
}
```