# Centering boxes in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center 3 boxes in the middle of my container. However, I cannot get it working.

What am I doing wrong?

HTML

```
<div id="boxes">
    <div class="box">Box1</div>
    <div class="box">Box2</div>
    <div class="box">Box3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#boxes {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: yellow;

    float: left;
}

#boxes .box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    margin: 10px;
    float: left;

    background-color: blue;
}
```

JSFiddle with the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/3cUF5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a crossbrowser solution, then use `display: inline-block` for inner boxes and align with `text-align: center` on parent.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RhBEz/1/

**Css**

```
#boxes {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

#boxes .box {
    display: inline-block;

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

---

A second approach is using `display: flex`, but this will work only on recent Chrome and Firefox:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2mxET/1/

*Css*

```
#boxes {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
}

#boxes .box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: +1 Also mind the [gap between inline(-block) elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875226/space-between-nowrap-inline-blocks/21875532#21875532) which increases the space between divs.

Comment: Works now. +1 to you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `float: left` on `.box` means they cannot be centered. You also needed to add `text-align: center` to `#boxes`

Please see a working version here http://jsfiddle.net/s455x/

Answer (score 1):

Just add margin:0 auto; for #boxes

CSS

```
#boxes {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: yellow;

    float: left;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Now your outer container #boxes is aligned to center

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/3cUF5/2/

```
#boxes {
    text-align: center;
}

#boxes .box {
    float: left; /* removed this line */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

When you're trying to center elements, it's not a good idea to use floats. You have two basic options when centering elements.

1. do `display: inline-block;` to the child elements, and `text-align: center;` to the parent element

   or
2. do `display: block;` to the element you want centered, as well as `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what browsers' you are trying to support but [FlexBox](http://joshbailey.net/a-thing-or-two-about-flexbox/) makes this super easy, and if non-supported browsers are a requirement then you can just provide a fallback that works.