# Align div content in the middle using only auto or %

Tags: html, css

i'm with some problems here.. I've tried a lot of different fixes for this, but none of them seems to work. I want to align the content of a div in the middle of another div.

I want to use only auto or % values because i want to make the website also for mobile devices.

This is the code i have so far: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xHpaF/
I want to make those red boxes aligned to the center of the wrap div.

If anyone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: In the future, please post your code here as well, instead of just the codepen. If codepen ever shuts down, this question wont' be able to help people reading it.

Comment: Yeah, i was in a hurry, so that was the fastest way. But i´ll keep that in mind =D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, first of all, your `<div id="content" />` is an ID, not a class. So change your `.content` in the CSS to `#content`. Second of all, float throws off the `text-align: center;`. If you remove that, and set it to `display: inline-block;`, it should fix your issues:

check it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ncviE/

css changes:

```
#content {
  width:auto; 
  height:250px; 
  margin:0 auto; 
  background:#0C0; 
  display:table-cell; 
  text-align:center;
}

.view {
   display: inline-block;
   float: none;
}
```

Comment: +1 Also mind [the gap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875226/space-between-nowrap-inline-blocks/21875532#21875532) between inline(-block) elements.

Comment: @HashemQolami just trying to tackle the issue that OP is having :) There are a lot of other things to consider, but there are resources out there for those separate issues.

Comment: The Id/Class problem was only when i posted in the codepen, in my website is ok. I'll give it a try to test it. I'll be back to tell you if i was able to fix that. Thanks for now.

Comment: @Chad Of course! just saying :) as the extra white space increases the space between the blocks and it may break the layout generally.

Comment: I could made it work! I little complex, i'm kind of new to those css tricks and tips. But i think i'm getting the way to do the stuffs. =D Thanks!