# does empty space play important role in html and css?

Tags: html, css

Try this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/r7vz3b4w/1/)**

Here you can see from `A to V` links having more space between borders (left & right) and from `w to z` you can see my expected output. Why I'm getting more space for A to V links..

Can some one suggest me how to solve it?

I tried everywhere `margin and padding as 0` and `outline to none`. Even after i tried reseting my css, I'm getting some space between lines (border left and right)

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/r7vz3b4w/5/) may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875226/space-between-nowrap-inline-blocks/21875532#21875532

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 3):

As these are inline-blocks elements because of your css, you need to write them like that :

```
<ul class="filter">
    <li><a href="#">A</a></li
   ><li><a href="#">C</a></li
   ><li><a href="#">D</a></li
   ><li><a href="#">E</a></li
   ><li><a href="#">F</a></li
   ><li><a href="#">G</a></li
   ><li><a href="#">H</a></li
   ><li><a href="#">I</a></li
   ><li><a href="#">J</a></li
   ><li><a href="#">K</a></li
   ><li><a href="#">L</a></li>
</ul>
```

The spaces between inline elements are rendered, so, using this "trick" there is no space anymore
http://jsfiddle.net/r7vz3b4w/4/

But you could also keep your html unchanged and tell mister css to make them floating with `float:left`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. As per the link given by Hashem Qolami , I tried `ul{font-size:0}` and my problem solved.. Thanks for your time once again :-)