# How to keep <li> elements on single line in fixed width?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am developing a website and I want a menu like the above image. This is what I have tried: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x98eaj92/)

**HTML**

```
         <div class="">
            <ul class="header-menu-ul">
            <li class="header-menu menu-link1-color"><a href="" class="header-menu-link ">ABC's Office</a></li>
            <li class="header-menu menu-link2-color"><a href="" class="header-menu-link ">Benefits</a></li>
            <li class="header-menu menu-link3-color"><a href="" class="header-menu-link ">NEW Brand</a></li>
            <li class="header-menu menu-link4-color"><a href="" class="header-menu-link ">Editorial</a></li>
            <li class="header-menu menu-link5-color"><a href="" class="header-menu-link ">Manger</a></li>
            <li class="header-menu menu-link6-color"><a href="" class="header-menu-link ">Extra</a></li>
            </ul>

            </div>
```

The problem I'm facing is it's taking a space between `<li>` tags.

Comment: You should [remove the white space between inline-blocks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875226/space-between-nowrap-inline-blocks/21875532#21875532) like so: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/x98eaj92/2/

Comment: fixed - http://jsfiddle.net/x98eaj92/4/

the space was caused by inline-block. to fix this you need to set the font size to 0 of the div container then set the font size in `<li>` again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just floated the list items to the left, like this:

```
.header-menu-ul li {
  float: left;
}
```

**WORKING FIDDLE**: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/x98eaj92/1/).

Comment: If you can just hit the V mark below the vote count, it will help everyone reading this question.

Comment: I mean the accept answer button... check mark, however you want to call it. Clicking it means that this answer worked for you, and other people that read the question will know that this is the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x98eaj92/3/)**

This will create an always single line menu unliek the floating solution where often items fall from position on small sizes + no spaces between the items.

**Code:**

```
.header-menu-ul{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.header-menu{
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my approach would be using inline-block and min-width. can also use percent in width (1oo% / total_li ).