# Two <li> are not lined up properly even tho they are the same width

Tags: css

[image]

```
    body {
    font: 18px/1.1em "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
}

a {
    font: 18px/1.1em "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 1280px;
    height: 800px;
    background-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
    margin: 100px 0 164px 170px;
}

.logo a {
    font-size: 65px;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 26px;
}

.main {
    margin-top: 94px;
}

    .main li {
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .main li.home {
        background-color: #3387ea;
        background-image: url(../img/home.png);
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }

    .main li.about {
        background-color: #f9be3e;
        background-image: url(../img/about.png);
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }

    .main li.portfolio {
        background-color: #d3573e;
        background-image: url(../img/portfolio.png);
        width: 280px;
        height: 150px;
    }

    .main li.photos {
        background-color: #59b0e2;
        background-image: url(../img/photos.png);
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }

    .main li.testimonials {
        background-color: #33af95;
        background-image: url(../img/testimonials.png);
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }

    .main li.hire {
        background-color:  #86a73f;
        background-image: url(../img/hire.png);
        width: 310px;
        height: 150px;
    }

    .main li.blog {
        background-color: #151a26;
        width: 440px;
        height: 150px;
    }

    .main li.contact {
        background-color: #7e5b8c;
        background-image: url(../img/contact.png);
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }
```

The bottom 's are not lined up with top ones even though they match each other in total width.

Each

has a margin-right 10px and margin-bottom 10px.

I am using reset style sheet to remove browser setting.

I cannot think of anything that will not allow it to align properly.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Serhiicss/pen/dApEg)

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because [the white-space between inline block elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875226/space-between-nowrap-inline-blocks/21875532#21875532) (in this case, the list items) also tabs and new lines between HTML elements are count as a white space.

You could either use CSS float or just remove the white space as follows:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://codepen.io/hashem/pen/ApuwE)**

```css
.main ul {
  font: 0/0 a; /* Set font-size and line-height to 0 for the container */
}

.main li {
  /* Then reset the valid value on list items */
  font: 18px/1.1em "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  /* other declarations */
}
```

There are couple of ways to remove the space between inline(-block) elements:

- Minimized the HTML
- Negative margins
- Comment the white space out
- Break the closing tag
- Set the font size of the parent to zero then reset that for children
- Float the inline items instead
- Use flexbox

Your choice.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Learned something new today :)

Comment: I used float instead of inline block. It seems like the best option :)

Comment: @serhii.css That would be my choice as well. While neither of `float` and `inline-block` are designed exactly for layout purposes, CSS float would be more helpful in this case; And don't forget to `clear` the float ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's because there's still a space between your tiles.
To solve this, make your hire me tile's width `315px`.

[image]