# Keep inner divs on same line though inner div width is greater than 100%

Tags: css

I'm playing around with a slide menu. I need the content `div` to have a width of 100% and menu to have width of 16% (it's a long story). Of course, this results in the content `div` being pused to the next line. Is there a way to keep the inner `divs` on the same line, even though total percenatge is greater than 100%, with the right part of the content `div` off the screen? Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s10yqj43/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a [`white-space: nowrap;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to the `#container` element then override that declaration on its children elements:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/s10yqj43/5/)**

```css
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#container > div {
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

In addition you may need to use `vertical-align: top;` to align the inline block elements (the columns in this case) vertically at the top of the `#container`.

> **[16.6 White space: the 'white-space' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop)**
>
> This property declares how white space inside the element is handled.
>   Values have the following meanings:
>
> **nowrap** value
>   This value collapses white space as for 'normal', but suppresses line breaks within text.

Also mind [the gap between inline block element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875226/space-between-nowrap-inline-blocks/21875532#21875532). Tabs and new lines in HTML counts a white space.

Answer (score 2):

Additional to white space in `#container` you can use `overflow:hidden` and `float:left` to `#menu` element to prevent an issue when menu contains large text:

```
#menu{
    width:16%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s10yqj43/3/)