# Extra space between nav links

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some extra space for my responsive nav links that is not being defined anywhere in the CSS. This space is removed after I reduce the page width. Can anyone identify the cause of the extra space, it is baffling me. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DjftP/

The nav is coded as follows:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="chunk-nav-hrz-fxd" data-nav-fxd="200">
        <nav>
            <a>Link1</a>
            <a>Link2</a>
            <a>Link3</a>
            <a>Link4</a>
        </nav>
        <nav class="nav-right">
            <a>Link5</a>
            <a>Link6</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

LESS:

```
.chunk-nav-hrz-fxd                    {.chunk; padding: 0; .clearfix}
.chunk-nav-hrz-fxd nav                {line-height: 40px; .clearfix; margin-bottom: 0; padding-left: 0; display: inline-block; float: left}
.chunk-nav-hrz-fxd .nav-right         {float: right}
.chunk-nav-hrz-fxd a                  { margin-bottom: 0; padding: @baseline/2 @baseline}
.chunk-nav-hrz-fxd a:hover            {text-decoration: none}
.chunk-nav-hrz-fxd a:last-child       {border-right: 0}
```

Before window resize with extra space:

[image]

After window resize with space somehow being removed:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there a gap between image and navigation bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290481/why-is-there-a-gap-between-image-and-navigation-bar)

Comment: Your fiddle is a bit different from the code you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your nav elements use `<a>` tags which have a default display of `inline`, so your whitespace is being counted.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bradleytrager/FA9W2/).  Where I removed all the whitespace between your HTML tags.

Comment: I'm still seeing the whitespace in the fiddle.

Comment: Which white space are you referring to?

Comment: @BradleyTrager Maybe the whitespace between links 5 and 6?

Comment: This does seem to have done the trick, but could you explain where abouts I had set the inline-block? Thanks!

Comment: @Alex `.img-thumbnail {}` had `display: inline-block;` set.

Comment: in `chunk-nav-hrz-fxd nav`

Comment: Sorry, there's a border-right which has the same colour as the background which made it seem as if there were 1px of whitespace, my bad.

Comment: The edited answer explains perfectly, thank you for clarifying Bradley.

Comment: I actually edited it again because I realized the inline display was just coming from the <a> tags by default.  But still the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your element are inline block, which give the roperties of block element and inline aswell.

One of the inline property is the white space character. When the HTML is compiling. it compile every whitespace character into a single whitespace (with the exception of `pre` elements). Return character, tabulation and space are all compiled as whitespace and create the visible space. See [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/9J9Er/) to see the said behavior.

But you resize function is using DOM manipulation method. When using those methods, it does not create the new line character or the tabulation like your source code. And this is why the whitespace aren't shown after resize.

## Solution : trigger the resize

```
$(window).smartresize(function () {
    checkSize()
}).trigger('resize');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DjftP/1/